# Sum every 5 values of object array

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

Say I have an object array of indeterminate length like this

```
jString = [
  {
    "value": "2,335.47"
  },
  {
    "value": "2,862.96"
  },
  {
    "value": "2,217.31"
  },
  {
    "value": "1,627.01"
  },
  {
    "value": "1,103.52"
  },
  {
    "value": "1,718.69"
  },
  {
    "value": "1,992.83"
  },
  {
    "value": "3,796.26"
  },
  {
    "value": "3,800.43"
  },
  {
    "value": "2,128.62"
  },
  {
    "value": "2,661.56"
  }
]
```

I need to get the sum average of every 5 elements and return as a new array

I figured a map function would work the best, but it's not working for me.

```js
 function sumAvg(arr) {
            var sum = 0;
            avg= arr.map(function(item){
              for(var i = 0; i <arr.length -1; i++){
                sum = (item.value[i] + item.value[i+1] + item.value[i+2] + item.value[i+3] + item.value[i+4])/5;
              }
              return item = sum;
            })
            return avg;
           }

           var avgString= sumAvg(jString);

           console.log(avgString);
```

Comment: This is not a JSON string, since *it's not a string*. This is a plain JS array with JS objects in it.

Comment: `get the sum average of every 5 elements and return as a new array` This is unclear. Do you want to get the sum, or the average, or a new array? Please post the desired output

Comment: The name of the variable `jString` is misleading. Neither is the content a string, nor is it "JSON" or a "JSON String"

Comment: @CertainPerformance partly my fault. I edited it to remove "json string" there. I'm actually not sure what it should be - an array, a value, an object. The code does seem to try and return an array but...it might just be a wrong implementation.

Comment: strings like `"2,128.62"` can never be "coerced" to Number, because of the `,`

Comment: When you say "every 5" ... do you mean the sum of indices 0...4, 5...9, 10...14 ... or 0...4, 1...5, 2...6 ... etc

Answer (score 2):

Your question is a little unclear about whether you want the sum of each consecutive 5 elements or the average. Here's the code to get the sums, with some additional notes on how to get the averages from it.

```js
const data = [{"value":"2,335.47"},{"value":"2,862.96"},{"value":"2,217.31"},{"value":"1,627.01"},{"value":"1,103.52"},{"value":"1,718.69"},{"value":"1,992.83"},{"value":"3,796.26"},{"value":"3,800.43"},{"value":"2,128.62"},{"value":"2,661.56"}];

// Create a new array
const out = [];

// While there are elements remaining
while (data.length > 0) {

  // `splice` off 5 elements from the array
  const next = data.splice(0, 5)

  // `reduce` over those 5 elements adding up the values
  // Note 1: If you want to get the average just add `/ 5`
  // to the end of this expression
  // Note 2: we have to remove the comma from the value string in
  // order to parse it properly
  const sum = next.reduce((a, b) => {
    return a + Number.parseFloat(b.value.replace(/,/g, ''));
  }, 0);

  // Push the stringified sum to the output array.
  out.push(sum.toFixed(2));
}

console.log(out);
```

Further reading

- [`splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)
- [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)
- [`toFixed`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed)

Comment: `"message": "SyntaxError: unexpected token: ')'",` - your reduce has an extra `)`

Comment: Why don't you divide by 5 like in the question?

Comment: The question isn't very clear. The title is "Sum every 5 values of object array", but the code suggests that the OP wants the average. It's easy enough to get the average from the `reduce` output if that's what the OP wants.

Comment: yeah sure ... it's just his code has `sum = (a + b + c + d + e)/5` - not a good name for the variable :p

Answer (score 0):

Map is not going to work the way you want. You are doing the calulation for each 5 element group, getting some of them 4 times.

You can get the first five elements, do your average, store it somewhere and then remove them. Repeat this until the array is empty

Answer (score 0):

I would end up using traditional looping and counting.

```js
 let jString = [
    {
        "value": "2,335.47"
    },
    {
        "value": "2,862.96"
    },
    {
        "value": "2,217.31"
    },
    {
        "value": "1,627.01"
    },
    {
        "value": "1,103.52"
    },
    {
        "value": "1,718.69"
    },
    {
        "value": "1,992.83"
    },
    {
        "value": "3,796.26"
    },
    {
        "value": "3,800.43"
    },
    {
        "value": "2,128.62"
    },
    {
        "value": "2,661.56"
    }
];

let result = [];
let ctr =0;
let resIndex=0;
for(index=0; index <jString.length; index++){
    if (ctr==5) {
      ctr=0;
      result[resIndex] = result[resIndex] / 5; // avg
      resIndex++;
    }
    var value = Number(jString[index].value.replace(/,/,''));
    if (ctr == 0) {
        result.push(value);
    } else {
        result[resIndex] = result[resIndex] + value;
    }
    ctr++;
    
    // handle last records avg if they aren't 5 in total
    if (index == jString.length-1 && ctr !=5) {
        result[resIndex] = result[resIndex] / ctr; 
    }
}

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function sumAvg(arr) {
            var sum = 0;
            avg= arr.map(function(item){
              for(var i = 0; i <arr.length -1; i++){
                sum = (item.value[i] + item.value[i+1] + item.value[i+2] + item.value[i+3] + item.value[i+4])/5;
              }
              return item = sum;
            })
            return avg;
           }

           var avgString= sumAvg(jString);

           console.log(avgString);
```

change sum in your for loop to something like this:

```
for(var i = 0; i <arr.length -1; i++){
                    sum += item.value[i];
                  }
```

then inside the for loop you can have something as follows:

```
if i == 5 then
sum = sum/5;
end if
```

that will return the average of the sum of your 5 items in your json. I assume that this is what you are looking for, i would not recommend this  **sum = (item.value[i] + item.value[i+1] + item.value[i+2] + item.value[i+3] + item.value[i+4])/5;**
As you will run into an indexing error, especially if the length of the json is unknown.

if you are looking at getting the average of the sum, after 5 values have been added together then adjust the if statement to say:

```
if i % 5 == 0 then
sum = sum/5;
end if
```

Hope this helps in any way.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want an average every 5 elements means an average of

0,1,2,3,4
1,2,3,4,5
2,3,4,5,6
3,4,5,6,7

etc

*I assume this because it looks like your code is trying to do this*

This should provide the result you need

```js
const input = [
      {
        "value": "2,335.47"
      },
      {
        "value": "2,862.96"
      },
      {
        "value": "2,217.31"
      },
      {
        "value": "1,627.01"
      },
      {
        "value": "1,103.52"
      },
      {
        "value": "1,718.69"
      },
      {
        "value": "1,992.83"
      },
      {
        "value": "3,796.26"
      },
      {
        "value": "3,800.43"
      },
      {
        "value": "2,128.62"
      },
      {
        "value": "2,661.56"
      }
    ];
    const result = Array.from({length:input.length-4}, (_, i) => Number((input.slice(i, i+5).reduce((acc, {value}) => acc + +value.replace(',', ''), 0)/5).toFixed(3)));
    
    console.log(result);
```

Regarding `.toFixed(3)`

This is to limit to 3 decimal places, as an average of 5 values to 2 decimal places will only ever be to 3 decimal places - using `toFixed` prevents values like 2029.2540000000001 and 2047.6619999999998 which can creep in to floating point Math

An alternative method, which is easier to read and perhaps a little faster (like who cares unless you have MILLIONS of entries)

```js
const input = [
  {
    "value": "2,335.47"
  },
  {
    "value": "2,862.96"
  },
  {
    "value": "2,217.31"
  },
  {
    "value": "1,627.01"
  },
  {
    "value": "1,103.52"
  },
  {
    "value": "1,718.69"
  },
  {
    "value": "1,992.83"
  },
  {
    "value": "3,796.26"
  },
  {
    "value": "3,800.43"
  },
  {
    "value": "2,128.62"
  },
  {
    "value": "2,661.56"
  }
];

const result = 
input.slice() // copy the input
.map(({value}) => +value.replace(',', '')) // map the value's to a Number
.reduce((acc, value, i) => {
    acc.total += value; // add to the total
    let len = acc.five.push(value); // push the current value
    if (len > 5) {
        acc.total -= acc.five.shift(); // if the length has exceeded 5, reduce the total by the first value, and remove it
    }
    if (acc.five.length == 5) { // if the length is 5, output an average
        acc.result.push(Number((acc.total / 5).toFixed(3)));
    }
    return acc;
}, {five:[], result:[], total:0})
.result; // we only want the resulting array
console.log(result);
```